# How can I get the cookie expiration for 'connect.sid' on client-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express, passport.js

My web application is using AngularJS, NodeJS, Express, and Passport. When I do a CTRL+Shift+I and look at the Cookies under the Resources tab on Google Chrome, I see 'connect.sid' that I would like get the expiration date from. Is it possible? I have tried using document.cookie on the client-side but nothing shows up.

This is the code I used to set up the expiration date for 'connect.sid'

```
 app.use(express.session({cookie : { maxAge: 3600000 * 24 * 30 * 2 }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not get the expiration date of the cookie from client side. document.cookie will only give you key=value pairs.

Comment: if and only if they are not HttpOnly